# Travel to India with expired Indian passport?

Tags: air-travel, passports, india, indian-citizens

I am on H4 dependent and an Indian citizen,my passport has expired 2 months back,can I travel to India at this moment with expired passport?

Comment: It is very difficult for an Indian citizen to renew an _expired_ passport _outside_ India. To avoid trouble you should renew your passport before it expires.

Comment: I do not think it is very difficult to renew.. expired or not.. Maybe extra checks, but if all is ok, they can not deny him passport. But for sure he can not travel on expired passport, as Airline will not let him board.. Better to renew the passport before travelling.. The question is.. for all the time thapassport was expired, he was kind of passportless?

Comment: @Davinder what is the question? You have typed a statement with a wisdom mark.  He was without a valid passport; what aspect of that were youquestioning?

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I meant.. Was he/she passportless in this time? Is it not same as stateless? Is it allowed in H4 Visa? (I have no idea) because generally, Tourist Visa (Multiple, long term), are valid only with a valid passport. In any case, IMHO, OP need-to/should renew passport before travelling.

Comment: @Davinder a passport is evidence of citizenship.  It is not synonymous with citizenship.  Babies are generally born with one or more citizenships, but with zero passports.  I do not know the rules in the US for nonimmigrants.  I suppose they are supposed to renew before expiration, but I suspect that falling to do so is pretty much a minor problem of an administrative nature.

Answer (score 10):

India may let you in if you get there. However, your biggest problem is that airlines will probably not let you board without a valid passport. And if you cannot board the flight, it is a moot question whether India will let you in. You should get an Indian passport or other travel document from an Indian consulate before you travel.

Comment: Airlines usually check for at least six months of passport validity before they let you board. However, I have noticed that they sometimes let you board with less validitiy as long as you sign a letter indemnifying them of any consequent liability. Not sure if they'd settle for this in case of an expired passport but they just might if you are traveling to your home country.

Comment: Airlines dont check for 6 month validity generally it is a visa stamping condition and not travel itself.  However the answer per se is right, no airline will allow you to board without valid papers

Comment: For India, Indian passports must be valid on arrival according to TIMATIC, nothing more nothing less

Comment: @ottodidakt It is not applicable for India. You need a passport that is valid on arrival in India.

Answer (score 7):

Airline will deny you boarding with expired passport. Only thing you can do is go to nearest Indian embassy and renew the passport. It can take two weeks.

If it is urgent to travel, you can directly approach the consulate and they will provide an emergency document that is valid only for returning to India. Once you reach India, you can renew it by applying online and going to local passport office.

Comment: I confirm this is correct: for many countries, TIMATIC states their own passports can be expired, but not for India