# Multiple b1 Visa doubts

Tags: b1-b2-visas, visa-renewals

My B1 visa is expiring on 10 Oct 2017 and passport on 7 Oct
can I enter US before expiry but stay for three months?
also what will happen if I don't renew passport?
also how to renew B1 visa individually?

Comment: Beyond any issues in the US, will your home country (what is it?) allow you entry on an expired passport? If so, you'll have to make sure you can transit  as well.

Comment: You did not mention when you plan to enter the US and when you plan to stay until.

Comment: before expiry I want to enter,date is not fixed,also stay for three months I mentioned,my home country,India

Comment: You're not going to be allowed by the airline to board a plane on your return trip with an expired passport. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60166/travel-to-india-with-expired-indian-passport

Comment: if such situation happens,how to renew passport?

Comment: "How to renew passport?": before you travel.  You are not required to wait until your current passport has expired; you can get a new passport beforehand and your current passport will be cancelled.  You can use your cancelled passport with the valid visa in conjunction with the new passport.

Comment: I am from India,anytime I can get date to travel,if I put to renew passport will be stuck in postal department

Answer (score 5):

The visa expiry is not an issue. You can use the visa to enter up to and including the day the visa expires.

The passport expiry is an issue. If your passport is from [this list of countries](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2), the date you are admitted until as a nonimmigrant can be no later than the day your passport expires. If your passport is from a country not on that list, the date you are admitted until as a nonimmigrant can be no later than 6 months before passport expires (which means you cannot enter if your passport is less than 6 months away from expiring).

So either you will not even be able to travel to the US (if your passport is not on that list), or you will be able to enter but you will only be admitted until Oct 7 at the latest, not as long as you want (if your passport is on that list).